# How to center a container in react-bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, containers, react-bootstrap

I'm developing a website using react-bootstrap, and I have a container whose width needs to be changed to 60%, and still be centered. I changed the width, but I can't find a way to center the container. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
import {Row, Col, Container, Button} from "react-bootstrap"
import '../CSS/Room.css'

const Room = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="roomfac fontReg">
                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logofridge.png" alt="Logo 1"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">Fridge</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logoAC.png" alt="Logo 2"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">AC</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logowifi2.png" alt="Logo 3"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">Wifi</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logotv.png" alt="Logo 4"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">TV</h3>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Room
```

And here's my  CSS:

```css
.roomfac {
    display: flex;
    widtH: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this CSS for your container to be centered.

```
.roomfac {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.roomfac{
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
    justify-content:center
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: look again the edited answer please

Comment: Yeah, now it's better.

Comment: didn't work also

Comment: this is not possible..can you share the fontReg class and where the Room compenent renders ? cause with those attributes in codesandbox is working